# Implementing Add Media Wizard with MediaWiki 1.16.0

Tags: php, javascript, wiki, mediawiki

I have MediaWiki 1.16.0 installed on a remote sever, with Apache+PHP 5.2.11 running. I have installed several extensions(namely: FCKEditor, Group access control) without a problem. However, I could not get  [Add Media Wizard](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Add_Media_Wizard) and [Upload Wizard](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UploadWizard) to work correctly(Try them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Enable_the_Add_Media_Wizard)). I have tried many things(with details below):

I downloaded and tried to install [JS2Support](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/JS2_Overview#JS2_Support_Extension) and [Add Media Wizard](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Add_Media_Wizard) by adding

```
# Base JS2 Support ( includes mwEmbed )
require_once( "$IP/extensions/JS2Support/JS2Support.php"  );
# Add Media Wizard
require_once( "$IP/extensions/AddMediaWizard/AddMediaWizard.php" );
```

to LocalSettings.php, however, when I checked the Special:Version page, only JS2Support is added under extensions, *not* Add Media Wizard.

At this point, if I edit a page on the Wiki, the editing tool bar shows the 
[Add Media Wizard](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Add_Media_Wizard) icon(A film reel) - but when I hover my mouse over, it *always* says "Loading Add Media Wizard," and I cannot click on it. Note that I have tried to disable FCKEditor(A rich text editor extension), but Add Media Wizard continues to behave the same way.

I also tried to install Add Media Wizard as a [mwEmbed](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MwEmbed) gadget, as seen in the [Wikipedia implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Enable_the_Add_Media_Wizard). The extension [Gadgets](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Gadgets) installed fine, but when I implemented [mwEmbed Standalone](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/JS2_Overview#mwEmbed_as_a_Gadget) to MediaWiki:Gadgets-definition and MediaWiki:Gadgets-mwEmbed, and MediaWiki:Gadgets-mwEmbed.js, the Wiki site begins to return a blank screen - I had to disable gadgets in LocalSettings.php to remove the entry from MediaWiki:Gadgets-definition page to get the Wiki back online.

I have always downloaded the latest trunk/svn for these extensions, which I believe to be compatible with MediaWiki 1.16.0(latest at the time of writing), but I have put in many hours of researching and trying different things... and still cannot get it to work.

At this point, I gave Add Media Wizard up and tried to install [Upload Wizard](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UploadWizard) (Which is part of MediaWiki's js2 extensions, using [JS2Support](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/JS2_Overview#JS2_Support_Extension)), but end up with the following result when I opened the Wiki,

> Internal error
>
> Javascript Module UploadWizard missing loader.js file
>
> Backtrace:
>
> #0 D:\dp\wiki\extensions\JS2Support\mwEmbed\includes\NamedResourceLoader.php(101): NamedResourceLoader::proccessModulePath('UploadWizard', 'extensions/Uplo...')
>
> #1 D:\dp\wiki\extensions\JS2Support\JS2Support.hooks.php(29): NamedResourceLoader::loadResourcePaths()
>
> #2 [internal function]: JS2SupportHooks::setup()
>
> #3 D:\dp\wiki\includes\Setup.php(370): call_user_func('JS2SupportHooks...')
>
> #4 D:\dp\wiki\includes\WebStart.php(132): require_once('D:\dp\wiki\incl...')
>
> #5 D:\dp\wiki\index.php(42): require_once('D:\dp\wiki\incl...')
>
> #6 {main}

I guessed that both of the problems with Add Media Wizard and Upload Wizard has something to do with Javascript support, and tried to set $wgEnableScriptLoader = true; but that didn't change anything.

Please let me know what could have gone wrong and how can I implement these extensions correctly. I'd really appreciate any advice and suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

Based on that error message, it looks like the extension is trying to use the [Resource Loader](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader) which wasn't introduced until 1.17. According to the infobox on UploadWizard, it's only supported in 1.19+ so it definitely uses Resource Loader as well. Looking in the [old 1.16 MediaWiki extension repo](http://svn.wikimedia.org/svnroot/mediawiki/tags/REL1_16_5/extensions/) I don't see either of those extensions listed so there doesn't appear to be older versions you can try. Without modifying a bunch of extension code to load all of the CSS and JS for the extension by hand, you aren't going to be able to do this.